# How do you deal with partially copied containers when the constructor throws?

Tags: c++, exception

I've been using c++ for a bit, but I really never used exceptions, and was writing code assuming that no exception was ever thrown, because I didn't use them. In a container below I construct each element and incrementing _end, so that the container always had the right size, so that in the destructor call it would destroy the right number. But the thing is that if an exception is thrown in the constructor then the destructor for my container class isn't called at all (I have learned):

```
struct ClassWhichMayThrowOnConstruction
{

    ClassWhichMayThrowOnConstruction() {
        
        if ((rand() % 2) == 0) throw;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct Container
{
    Container(std::size_t size)
    {
        _begin = malloc(size * sizeof(T));
        _end = _begin;
        capacity = size;

        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            new (&_begin[i]) T();
            ++_end;
        /* LET'S SAY THE FIRST THREE CONSTRUCT OK BUT THE FOURTH ONE THROWS EXCEPTION */
        }
    }
    T* _begin;
    T* _end;
    std::size_t capacity;
    
    
};
```

So the destructor for my container class isn't called if ClassWhichMayThrowOnConstruction throws on construction, then is it my job to catch every possible exception that may be thrown from that class and destroy exactly the number that I constructed to prevent a leak?

Also, ignoring the fact that something might throw has been working perfectly well as I don't use any functions that throw. The one condition that I might want to handle is if malloc or new (or whatever memory allocator I use) cannot allocate and I need to free memory, but thinking about it, is there actually anything you can do if you can't allocate memory? I'm having trouble thinking of what you can do in this case.

Comment: `is it my job to catch every possible exception that may be thrown from that class and destroy exactly the number that I constructed to prevent a leak?` yes.

Comment: `is there actually anything you can do if you can't allocate memory?` Maybe, maybe not, that is not up to you as the library author to decide. You can throw `std::bad_alloc` or signal the issue to the user in other way but let them deal with that.

Comment: Your call to `malloc` isn't the only problem. What if `T()` *also* allocates memory, or fails to get some other resource? That might throw as well.

Comment: You don't have to *catch* every exception, just account for it (that *is* your job). This is C++, use RAII. If you instantiate a guard that references `i` and `_begin`, you can have its destructor do the releasing.

Comment: first you need to decide what exception guarantees you want to give to your user. None, can be a viable option.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica You mean call the destructor from the constructor? The destructor isn't called by the compiler if it throws insisde the constructor.

Comment: No, the guard won't be of the container's type

Answer (score 2):

By manually invoking destructors on the partial copy.

You can abstract the part that calls `T`'s constructor like this:

```cpp
template<typename T> 
void uninitialized_fill(T* start, T* finish, const T& x) {
    T* p;
    try {
        for (p = start; p != finish; ++p) {
            new(static_cast<void*>(p)) T(x);
        }
    } catch(...) {
        for (T* q = start; q != p; ++q) q->~T();
        throw;
    }
}
```

And then call it in a try block whenever you want to call `T`'s constructor:

```cpp
            try {
                uninitialized_fill(...);
            } catch (...) {
                // fix class invariants here
                throw;
            }
```

This example rethrows the the exception thrown by T. You can [read  about throw](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw).